# how to create a php script with parameters

Tags: php

I have a small issue, I want to create a simple php script callable from external program or whatever.
I tried :

```
<?php
var_dump($argv);
?>
```

then call it `http://localhost/test/script.php?a=test` 
and I got :

```
undefined argv
```

in shell everything is fine :

```
php -q script.php foo bar
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "script.php"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "foo"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "bar"
}
```

When I use `$argv = $_GET;` I get HTTP working : `http://localhost/test/script.php?test="abc"` gives `array(1) { ["test"]=> string(5) ""abc"" }` but shell gives array(0) !!!!!

How can I do to be able to call it from command line and from web browser. ?
many thanks

Answer (score 0):

$argv is only to get arguments when running a script from command line. ([doc](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php))

If you would like to get parameters from a URL, you should use [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

```
<?php 
$a = $_GET['a']; 
echo $a; 
?>
```

If you would like to get all URL parameters, you can use var_dump($_GET);

Answer (score 0):

The Problem here is, that $_GET are Parameters only from an URL, where the $argv is only when you call it by Command Line.

Why not checking with (isset) if there are arguments (and doesent matter from Command Line or URL).

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET)) {
    $parameters = $_GET;
} else if(isset($argv)) {
    $parameters = $argv;
} else {
    // no parameters 
}

?>
```

Comment: in both cases, isset($_GET) is true

Comment: Try: if (!empty($_GET)) {